# Need Help Running Process at Bootup

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

Tried guide from [here.](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/start-service-at-boot/)
Edited this file with nano: /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.

.service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=DOESN'T WORK.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/otsmanager/NOSTWINDOWS2/script.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get this output in the console:

```
root@167-114-137-36:/home/otsmanager/NOSTWINDOWS2# sudo systemctl status myservice
● myservice.service - DOESN'T WORK.
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2021-06-19 20:26:13 CEST; 6min ago
    Process: 12951 ExecStart=/home/otsmanager/NOSTWINDOWS2/script.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 12951 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
     Memory: 2.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/myservice.service

Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12990]: directories currently searched are:
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12990]: - /root/.local/share
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12990]: - /usr/local/share/
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12990]: - /usr/share/
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12954]: 002a:err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140_1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\otsmanager\\NOSTWIN>
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12954]: 002a:err:module:import_dll Library mpir.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\otsmanager\\NOSTWINDOWS2\\the>
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12954]: 002a:err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140_1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\otsmanager\\NOSTWIN>
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12954]: 002a:err:module:import_dll Library pugixml.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\otsmanager\\NOSTWINDOWS2\\>
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 script.sh[12954]: 002a:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\otsmanager\\NOSTWINDOWS2\\theforgottens>
Jun 19 20:26:13 167-114-137-36 sudo[12953]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: so, the log seems to be pretty precise on what doesn't work. Also, are you sure you want to run this as root?

Comment: Yes but when I run the command from the terminal without systemd, the process works. I also changed workingdirectory and that didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Now when I edit the service file to
Description=DOESN'T WORK.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=chdir /home/otsmanager/NOSTWINDOWS2 && wine /home/otsmanager/NOSTWINDOWS2/theforgottenserver.exe

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target  I get myservice.service: Unit myservice.service has a bad unit file setting.

Comment: you say "when **I** run the command from the terminal": as *root* or as other user *otsmanager* (or some other user)?

Comment: yes. The server goes online.

Comment: you have not answered my question: **as root or as other user otsmanager (or some other user)?** Which user?

Comment: Both work for some reason.

Comment: Ok. but wine keeps a per-user WINEPREFIX, so these two tools will then probably access different `config.lua` files. I take it you *don't* want to run this as root – if it works as a normal user, it shouldn't have these privileges.

Comment: how do I edit the WINEPREFIX?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126665/discussion-between-neo-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: Have your searched the WineHQ website? And remember, a "service" runs in an entirely different environment than a shell you type commands in. Especially when adding yet another layer of abstraction such as `wine`, which usually recommends not running wine itself as root for a good reason...,

Comment: Yes I searched the wineHQ website. I just don't know how to import the WINEPREFIX variable

Comment: Do I have to run winecfg?

Comment: Or is there a command I can enter so my service gets the WINEPREFIX to load?

Comment: That is not the only issue. However, check `man env` for hints and clues. Depending on many factors, remember, the host GUI (xwin) will also need to be up and running for wine to work, which usually does not get started until the very end of a Unix boot-and-startup sequence--if a all.

Comment: I'm able to run wine without the GUI. Just need to get the service to run it at bootup.

Comment: Another suggestion: Write a shell script to handle most of the start/stop/restart details, and have have the *.service module call the shell script instead of calling wine directly. he script can then set up the runtime environment before starting the wine process. Take a look a other *.service files that do this to see examples.

Comment: Ok i edited .bashrc to include export WINEPREFIX=/home/otsmanager/NOSTWINDOWS2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126666/discussion-between-neo-and-c-m).

Comment: That is not where you want to do it. Bash documentation gives specifics on when bashrc is loaded--and when it is ignored.